# PDFium scale up PDF before converting to bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, png, pdfium

I'm using PDFiumSharpV2 in a .NET6 Web Api project to convert the first page of a multipage PDF to PNG.  It's working just fine except the resulting PNG gives the impression that the PDF is zoomed out.  The text is too small to read.  I'm having trouble finding the correct method in PDFium to say, zoom the PDF 20% before converting to image.

I'm converting PDF to Bitmap to PNG

```
    // PDF to image

    using (var doc = new PdfDocument(docObj.PdfBytes))
    {
         var page1 = doc.Pages[0];
         using (var bitmap = new PDFiumBitmap((int)page1.Width, (int)page1.Height, true))
         {
              page1.Render(bitmap);
              using (var memoryStreamBmp = new MemoryStream())
              {
                   bitmap.Save(memoryStreamBmp);
    
                   using (var imageBmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStreamBmp))
                   {
                        using (var memoryStreamPng = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                             imageBmp.Save(memoryStreamPng, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                             System.Drawing.Image pngImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStreamPng);
                             var pngBytes = memoryStreamPng.ToArray();
                             docObj.ImageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pngBytes);
                             pngImage.Save("download_test_image.png");
                        };
                   }
              }
         }
    }
```

I tried manually increasing the width and height arguments that are passed into PDFiumBitmap(), but all this did was add an empty border around the bitmap within the PNG.  So the PNG's dimensions matched what I specified but the actual page content didn't get any larger.

Is there a different method or technique to scaling up the PDF before converting to bitmap?

Comment: The first line of code shows how I'm loading a PDF.  I'm passing a byte array to PdfDocument.  There's no issues with the page either.  I'm calling page 1 with index 0 and that's exactly what I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong on two points:

1. The border I saw in my .png image was being set somewhere prior to exporting  from PDF to image.  Although I have not found a way to alter the border or remove it I have isolated it's origin to somewhere in the process of instantiating PdfDocument from the byte array.  The byte array comes from a PDF that's generated from a Google Sheet.  My guess is that the border is a page margin that I cannot control via API calls.  I have a work-around for this, explained below.
2. Improving the resolution of the final image ***CAN*** be achieved by passing larger values for width and height into PDFiumBitmap().  The default size of the PDF page was resulting in an image size of 612 x 792.  By increasing those arguments to 1350 x 2400 it produced an image with very readable text.

Even with a higher resolution image output, I still needed to remove the empty margins.  I did this by cropping the bitmap before saving it to .png.  A combination of examining the margin sizes in GIMP and trial and error got me to the right starting x and y values for the crop area.

```
// PDF to image
using (var doc = new PdfDocument(docObj.PdfBytes))
{
    var page1 = doc.Pages[0];
    int sheetWidth = (int)page1.Width;
    int sheetHeight = (int)page1.Height;
    int startingImageWidth = 1350;
    int startingImageHeight = 2400;
    using (var bitmap = new PDFiumBitmap(startingImageWidth, startingImageHeight, true))
    {
        page1.Render(bitmap);
        using (var memoryStreamBmp = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(memoryStreamBmp);

            using (var imageBmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStreamBmp))
            {
                // crop the image
                int cropX = 100;
                int cropY = 150;
                int cropWidth = startingImageWidth - (2 * cropX);
                int cropHeight = startingImageHeight - (2 * cropY);

                Bitmap croppedImage = ((Bitmap)imageBmp).Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight), imageBmp.PixelFormat);

                using (var memoryStreamImg = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    croppedImage.Save(memoryStreamImg, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStreamImg);
                    var imgBytes = memoryStreamImg.ToArray();
                    docObj.ImageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
                    image.Save("download_test_image.png");
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```